# Simpleweatherjs doesn't work when running from.apk and loading files locally

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create an android app which should just show the temperature with the jquery plugin simpleweatherjs in Phonegap. When I start the app with the Phonegap Developer App from the server that was started with `phonegap serve` everything works. But when I create an .apk with `phonegap build android` and install it on a device the temperature does not show.

I know that it would work if I'd create my own server (https://github.com/monkeecreate/jquery.simpleWeather/issues/75).

Is there any way of getting this app to work with the .apk file without creating a server?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.simpleWeather({
                    location: 'Austin, TX',
                    woeid: '',
                    unit: 'c',
                    success: function(weather) {
                        $("#test").html(weather.temp);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Part of config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
</platform>
```

Comment: Do you have whitelist plugin installed?

Comment: I have, but why should this plugin help? I thought that by default only file:// is allowed, and as the simpleweather is called from file:// and not from http:// it should work.

Comment: whitelist plugin is to allow external connections. If you don't have the plugin no connections are allowed. So if you have it, can you share your config.xml to see how did you configure it?

Comment: I added a part of my config.xml.

Comment: Do you have access tags? those are the ones that handle external connections.
Also, that version of the plugin is very old, latest is 1.3.3

Comment: The access tag is set to allow all request.

Comment: I don't know why but after adding the whitelist plugin again, it works. Thank you very much.